# Plese Help me about PreferredSize Debug

Tags: flutter, dart

Issue in PreferredSize required
this is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('flutter'),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {
            },
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {                
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert), 
              onPressed: () {
              },
            )
          ],
          flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.photo_camera,
              size: 75.0,
              color: Colors.white70
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bottomSheet: (
          PreferredSize(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 50.0,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Mybutton')
              )
            ),
          )
        ),
        body: null,
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PreferredSize widget need a PreferredSize so you should declare that. It can be fromWidth, fromHeight or fromRadius, I assume you need height for your case, so check below code and write your preferred height value instead of 50.

```
PreferredSize(
   preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
            child: Container(
```